# Text widget rendering twice

Tags: flutter, dart, rendering

In this code when I drag the widget the text inside the widget becomes red and there is yellow underline.
I think the text widget is rendering twice.
I want when dragging the text widget shouldn't be rendering twice dragging widget should looks the grid view items.
how to solve this problem?
Below here is my code.

```
DraggableGridViewBuilder(
              primary: false,
              cacheExtent: 10,
              semanticChildCount: 10,
              addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
              restorationId: "sdfs",

              key: UniqueKey(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                    (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3),
              ),
              children: gridViewList,
              isOnlyLongPress: false,
              dragCompletion: (gridViewList, int beforeIndex, int afterIndex) {
                DraggableGridItem item = gridViewList.removeAt(beforeIndex);

                gridViewList.insert(afterIndex, item);
                item = gridViewList.removeAt(afterIndex);
                gridViewList.insert(beforeIndex, item);
                debugPrint(
                    " after index ===> $afterIndex, before index ==>$beforeIndex");
              },
              dragFeedback: (list, index) {
                return draggableListView[index].child;
              },
              shrinkWrap: true,
              keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
              addRepaintBoundaries: true,
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
              // dragChildWhenDragging: (list, index) {
              //   return null;
              // },
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
                  decelerationRate: ScrollDecelerationRate.fast),

              dragPlaceHolder: (List<DraggableGridItem> list, int index) {
                return PlaceHolderWidget(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
              },
              // dragChildWhenDragging: ,
            )
```

this is my widgets

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

import 'custom_text_widget.dart';

class StickyNoteDragFeedbackWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StickyNoteDragFeedbackWidget({super.key, required this.note});

  final String note;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.5,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.sp),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.sp),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.amber,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
      child: CustomTextWidget(
        text: note,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

list

```
List<DraggableGridItem> draggableListView = List.generate(
      _controller.currentNotes.length,
      // data.length,
      (index) => DraggableGridItem(
        child: StickyNoteDragFeedbackWidget(
          note: "${_controller.currentNotes[index]!.sticky}",
        ),
        isDraggable: true,
      ),
    );
```